# Select Sections with Country Exception

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine, dql

I have a problem with a query:

I have a table with "sections" and another table with a Many to Many of SectionCountryException where only I have the values ​​of the countries do not want to appear.

Let me explain: I have many sections and I want some sections are not available in some countries.

Now I have this dql in a Section Table:

```
$dql = $this->createQuery('se')
->leftJoin('se.SectionCountryExceptions sce')
->whereNotIn('sce.value',$countryCode)
->orderBy....
```

but I know that's not right, but not how to do it ....

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered myself ...

```
    $dql = $this->createQuery('se')
                ->andWhereNotIn('se.id', $this->getExceptionsArray());
```

and the function:

```
    private function getExceptionsArray()
        {
            $countryCode = sfConfig::get('app_default_country_code');
            $sectionCountryExceptions = Doctrine::getTable('SectionCountryException')->findByValue($countryCode);

            $exceptions = array();
            foreach ($sectionCountryExceptions as $exception)
            {
                $exceptions[] = $exception->getSection()->getId();
            }

            return $exceptions;
        }
```